# thead element and scrolling is not working

Tags: html

I have a hard time to understand `thead` element:

Per definiton:

> enables user agents to support scrolling of table bodies
>   independently of the table head and foot. When long tables are
>   printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each
>   page that contains table data."

Does above mean the thead remains static to the viewer and body of a large table will be scrolled?

If that is the case I cannot not make this happen, even though the syntax of `thead`, `tfoot`, and `tbody` is very simple.

I did print the page and I don't see thead section printed on top of every page.

Comment: Do note the wordings "*enables* user agents to support" and "*may* be repeated". This is not mandated by the specs, it merely provides the logical groupings neccessary to support such functionality.

Comment: "Enables user agents to support" doesn't mean user agents do support this natively. If you want to get this functionality you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supposed to stay static and the other part move when scrolling. The feature is only when printing a page using tables, it would repeat it, althoug this doesn't work in all browsers (doesn't work in google chrome).

edit:
And yeah, you might want to add this css to work on some more browsers

```
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

(but it still wont work in chrome)

Comment: I used IE and I see head and footer were printed on every page.